# error in depencency about tensorflow and launcher icon

Tags: flutter, dart, tensorflow, dependencies, face-recognition

Because tflite_flutter_helper >=0.2.0 depends on image ^3.0.2 and flutter_launcher_icons 0.13.1 depends on image ^4.0.15, tflite_flutter_helper >=0.2.0 is incompatible with flutter_launcher_icons 0.13.1.
And because no versions of flutter_launcher_icons match >0.13.1 <0.14.0, tflite_flutter_helper >=0.2.0 is incompatible with flutter_launcher_icons ^0.13.1.
So, because facial_recog4 depends on both flutter_launcher_icons ^0.13.1 and tflite_flutter_helper ^0.3.1, version solving failed.

Solution of this error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.